# javascript not working with HTML5

Tags: javascript, css, html

I started to implement some new html5 features (standards, nothing fancy) in my project. Just the standard header, footer, aside, ect. For some reason a javascript code that I used on a past project doesn't work now and I can't figure out what the problem is.

I compared the code (html/javascript) with my new project and the past project (with javascript working) and I don't see any difference. The only thing I can think of is the change in html versions.

By the way Im trying to implement a script that highlights a current link from a menu. It is supposed to use javascript to add/remove a ".selected" code the anchor tags in the menu and relates to the current page and link.

here is the code:

```
<aside>
        <section>
            <Strong>Quick Links</strong>
                <menu id="side_menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="application.php">Sign Up</a></li>
                        <li><a href="testimonials.php">Testimonials</a></li>
                        <li><a href="diploma.php">The Process</a></li>
                        <li><a href="diploma.php">Course Listings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.php">American High School</a></li>
                     </ul>
                </menu> 

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var loc = window.location.href; // The URL of the page we're looking at
                $('#side_menu a').each(function() {
                    if (loc.indexOf(this.href) !== -1) { // If the URL contains the href of the anchor
                            $(this).addClass('selected'); // Mark it as selected
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>

        </section>
</aside>
```

Here is the link to the site **[here](http://www.skyviewmarketing.net/clients/BobKane/AmericanHighSchool/application.php)** (Side Panel)

I would appreciate any help on this issue. I spent hours trying to figure this out. Thanks for any help.

gdinari

Comment: Are you using Prototype and jQuery side by side? Or any other js frameworks? I had this problem on a "ready to run" package my client bought, I had to setup a noConflict for jQuery. This might be the case for you too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem is that you're trying to use Prototype before you've included it. Move your script tag for `js/prototype.js` above your script tag for `js/drop-o-matic.js`.

If you use a debugger (Chrome's Dev Tools, Firebug for Firefox, Script Debugger for IE, ...) it should tell you that. In this case, for instance, Chrome's Dev Tools showed me `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<an HTMLDocument> has no method 'observe'` , which immediately pointed me in the right direction — your DOM loaded function isn't being run because you're trying to hook it up before `document.observe` is added by Prototype.

---

After you fixed the above, the console said `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<an HTMLDocument> has no method 'ready'`. And that's because you're trying to use jQuery code without including jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var loc = window.location.href; // The URL of the page we're looking at
    $('aside li a').each(function() {
        if (loc.indexOf(this.href) !== -1) { // If the URL contains the href of the anchor
            $(this).addClass('selected'); // Mark it as selected
        }
    });
});
```

You **can** use jQuery as well as Prototype if you like, but if it's just for that snippet, I'd convert it to Prototype code instead:

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
    var loc = window.location.href; // The URL of the page we're looking at
    $$('aside li a').each(function(link) {
        if (loc.indexOf(link.href) !== -1) { // If the URL contains the href of the anchor
            link.addClassName('selected'); // Mark it as selected
        }
    });
});
```

If you're using jQuery code elsewhere, you'll want to include jQuery and use [`jQuery.noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/), which allows Prototype to keep the `$` symbol (you have to use `jQuery` instead where you want jQuery's function, or use the jQuery load function as a scoping function).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! The funny thing is that I did what you said and it ended up fixing another js problem I had, but the side menu highlights still don't work. Do you think it could be the reference that Im using in the js? I first used "#side_menu a" then I tried "aside li a," but it didn't work... Do you know what the problem could be?

Comment: @gdinari: Looks to me like you're trying to use jQuery code on a page/site that is set up to use Prototype, and not including jQuery. Updated my answer.

Comment: Ok what I tried was converting the prototype.js with the code that you provided, but noting. I guess I have to use the JQuery.noConflict with my original code? Im not completely sure, javascript/jquery is new to me. I'll thoroughly go through your advice and try to make it work. If you have any other suggestions, please let me know. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @gdinari: There was a bug in my translation from jQuery -> Prototype (I should have used `addClassName`, not `addClass`). The translation is functional now. I don't know whether it's necessarily what you want, but it seems to basically work: http://jsbin.com/uriyi3/4 In that example, there are four links, two of which are to that same page (one absolute, one relative). If they match the page location, they should get a grey background. For me, they do. Good luck with it.

Comment: Thanks so much! I looked over some of the past answers to my other questions but couldn't apply the logic to this situation. But the sample in link you provided helped a lot. I have to do a lot reading up on js. Thanks again.